# config.yaml is not setting up a new context

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a kubernetes Config file such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: test-sim-development
    namespace: test-sim
    user: developer
  name: test-sim
```

When I issue a command such as:

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig infra_k8/config.yaml set-context test-sim && kubectl config use-context test-sim
```

I get back the following error output:

```
Context "test-sim" modified.
error: no context exists with the name: "test-sim"
```

Why is it not finding the "test-sim" name? It is clearly referenced according to the [kubernetes docs.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 1):

it seems you’re trying to change the config by setting a context and you’re not providing the config to the change context command. So do this

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig=infra_k8/config.yaml use-context test-sim
```

The setters are used when you want to add more entries to the config file, so you don’t need that command when changing context.